# Is there a java-only equivalent to scala's parser generators?

Tags: java, scala, parsing, text-parsing

Scala has an amazingly simple way to create parsers. Is there a fairly equivalent way to doing the same thing in the Java-only world that doesn't take a week of learning curve?

Comment: Without operator overloading and implicits? Possible, but it will probably be far, *far* more ugly to use.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think so. Last time I looked at antlr, it was a beast. Has it gotten better? What is the simplest library I could use for a DSL that isn't really that complex - a similar complexity to Markdown.

Comment: Wait, are you asking about parsing in general (including "external" parser generators) or about "embedded" parser combinators? I assumed the latter. But if you use a parser generator with its own DSL, there's no reason it shouldn't be pretty and lightweight.

Comment: well, both. I love the way scala does it - bnf notation is awesome. But if java has no such thing, I'll take the easiest thing to work with I can get.

Comment: I forget the name of it actually... it's been awhile since I used it. I used to use scala's BNF notation library. Is that a combinator? I don't remember (sorry, it's been many months). I would use it again, but I can't use scala for this :(

Comment: Antlr is your best bet, although it may partially depend on what you're trying to parse.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I hope it's simpler than it was years ago. Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused by this discussion.   Scala's parser generators use BNF, that doesn't surprise me.   So does virtually everybody else, including ANTLR, which is one of many Java parser generators that use BNF.  What is it about Scala ease of user over ANTLR?  If you are going to address all the issues that ANTLR addresses, I'd expect you to have similar complexity.  "Scala the language" avoids all this somehow?

Comment: I am a little ignorant of antlr these days. I don't program as much as I used to. I just remember using scala's bnf library and had an amazingly complex parser setup in just a few hours. The number of lines of code all neatly packed and easily understood was just amazing. Is antlr like this too? If it is, i will be overjoyed. If it requires working with 10's of files and all sorts of complexity, then I will be less happy ;)

Comment: When building parsers, usually the "easy" part is encoding the grammar as a BNF.  For very simple languages, this is often just a page of BNF rules by itself.   What is not so easy is all the additional stuff: you don't want "just" a parser, that simply says "yes that's legal" or "no, you can't write that".  If you want to capture the structure of the parsed code, convert digit strings into binary values, skip over escape characters allow in literal strings, you have to write a bunch of other stuff, e.g., those multiple files you detest.  Scala has no obvious way to better at this than ANTLR.

Comment: [At the risk of bragging, our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit will build abstract syntax trees with just the grammar.  This is the easiest system I've ever used (I'm the designer, natch :) for getting ASTs just EBNF.   DMS isn't better when it comes to specifying lexical syntax or conversions; sometimes trouble is just trouble.

Comment: why can't you use scala? Doesn't scala compile to java byte code? Can't you write the parser in scala and expose the AST via a java wrapper? Who would know the difference?

Comment: @Kevin: The scala libraries in the classpath would be a dead give-away ;) haha. Anyway, I've been learning ANTLR and it's not terribly hard I guess. It is one more thing to learn though, and getting used to the error messages is a little interesting. I hope I can get what I need up in running in a few hours. Let's hope ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the lerning curve, but in the Java world, the [ANTLR Parser Generator](http://www.antlr.org/) is very well regarded and considered among the best.

Comment: I went with ANTLR. I don't think ANTLR is as good as the scala parser combinators though. I had to give it a lot more assistance in the parsing using lexical boolean members. The scala grammar needed none of this. I think ANTLR needs more help from the dsl author to do a job that I think it can infer on its own. Anyway, I managed to get it to work, although I think the scala version would have been shorter and less complicated as a whole. And there would have been no code generation either. Still, it served it's purpose.

Answer (score 1):

How robust and how configurable does the parser need to be? If the grammar is fairly simple and stable you could just use a recursive descent parser, which uses methods that represent each grammar production rule. I think the output would be roughly what JavaCC would produce, as they are both top-down.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

Hope this might be helpful.

Comment: isn't that basically what ANTLR generates?

Comment: Yes, as I understand that is true. However, learning and configuring ANTLR might take as much time as coding a simple RD parser. The choice to use a parser generator is based on the complexity of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Manning publications has a book, "[DSLs in Action](http://www.manning.com/ghosh/)", that covers Java in the beginning.

But, you may want to look at perhaps using Groovy to write your DSL, as there is a great deal of opportunities in a dynamic language, and it would have a shorter learning curve than Scala does.

For an introduction you can start with http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Writing+Domain-Specific+Languages.

The book I mentioned also covers using antlr, and when it makes sense to use and when it doesn't, so if you want to get a better understanding of how to write and maintain a DSL it is an excellent book.

Comment: I would be surprised if scala is off limits but groovy is acceptable. He doesn't seem concerned about scaala's complexity; he says he likes it, but just can't use it for some unstated reason.

Comment: @Kevin - The "week learning curve" implies, to me, that the complexity may be an issue.  Groovy has a much shorter learning curve.

Comment: In the comments he says can't use scala, and antlr is a beast. So I took his statement to mean "somthing simpler than antlr" in pure java, hopefully as simple as scala external dsls.

Comment: Yeah, I don't find scala hard. In fact, I've written a parser in scala before and it was about as easy as I could possibly imagine it to be. I don't find scala as a language to be that hard - it's easier than what a lot of other things, but I guess the way your mind thinks is going to make some things easier and other harder. People raise more smoke about it than they should. The parsing library was quite natural honestly. I had something usable in a few hours, and I really liked the fact that it was all done in scala and no external tools and files. Polyglot can go to hell.

Comment: @egervari - You may find the book to be useful though.